How to change spinner Increment values?
I would like to change the spinner increment value from 0.1 to 0.01. So that when I press an arrow it changes the value by 0.01. Is this possible?


No, unfortunately not - see the answer from @MarkusvonBroady below. Alternatively you can only drag with the mouse, if you hold the Shift key while doing this you have an increment of 0.01, but I guess you knew already that you can make finer adjustments with this. Would have been convenient if it worked for clicking the arrows as well ;)

Thanks shift will do.

I don't think this is possible. The workaround I see myself and others using is to pass a "Value" node through multiply/divide like this:

Imgur mirror (SE image hosting has problems)
